# update oracle DB data from CSV file using Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, csv

Need to update oracle DB table with data from CSV using hibernate. Is there any prepared statement batch update equivalent in Hibernate or Is there any optimal Hibernate approach in updating DB data from CSV?

Comment: You could check [Fastnate](https://fastnate.org/), which offers support for exactly that scenario.

Comment: That is the requirement and the project is implemented using Spring and Hibernate. It is not a very big CSV file, so how can this task be implemented using hibernate?

Comment: Fastnate is not a replacement for Hibernate - it is an more a "addon". So it wouldn't break the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is one of the `ORM` tools.

> **Object-relational mapping (ORM, O/RM, and O/R mapping tool)** in
>   computer science is a programming technique for converting data
>   between incompatible type systems in object-oriented programming
>   languages. This creates, in effect, a "virtual object database" that
>   can be used from within the programming language.

It means using ORM you have to:

1. deserialize data from **CSV**
2. map it to the **objects**
3. then serialize objects and store it to relational **DB**.

Don't you find it redundantly?

> Is there any optimal Hibernate approach in updating DB data from CSV?

The answer is not. There is no any optimal Hibernate approach because it's redundant meaningless work to use ORM. In this case plane **DAO** layer is much more effective and suitable.

Comment: That is the requirement and the project is implemented using Spring and Hibernate. It is not a very big CSV file, so how can this task be implemented using hibernate?